# Meteor: Get next/prev unpublished document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection with thousands of documents. When a user logs in, I publish the 40 most recent documents this user has access to and display them in a list.

The user may click either of the documents to play them in a new view. When doing so, I'd like to expose a previous & next button, loading the next document in the list.

The user may sort the list of documents on any chosen key, such as `title`, `date`, `username`. The next/prev document thereby depend on the current sort order of the list.

Further, users can manually enter the URL to play a document, so the next/prev document may not be among the 40 most recent documents. This means we'll need a mechanism to efficiently determine the next/prev on the server side.

Some caveats:

- I can't publish the next/prev document using a `$gte` or `$lte` and `limit: 1` because some documents have identical values for certain keys, such as `username`, and will end up republishing the same documents when pressing 'next', effectively ending up in a loop. This is also true even if we use secondary sorting.
- I don't want to publish the entire list for performance reasons.
- I don't want to query the entire collection from the database, find the current document's position by looping through the array, and returning the next and previous document, simply because there are potentially tens of thousands of documents and a user may want to press the next button many times quickly, so this is too slow.
- One solution is to publish the entire list, but only the `_id` field and nothing else. This may solve the sort problem but doesn't help with speed: I'd like the next/prev document published in its entirety so that it loads in the background for faster navigation between documents.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Why don't you just use `$gte`/`$lte` with some larger limit so you know you will have different documents, and just do some extra iteration on the client side?

Comment: Because there may be thousands with the same value. Like the keys 'username' and 'amountOfPlays' (default is 0). I'd have to limit 1000 to make it work then.